# How proficient is Leo Varadkar in the Irish language?

Tags: languages, republic-of-ireland

The Irish language, and official support for it, is a major political issue in Ireland (and has been so since the inception of Irish nationalism). This includes politicians' abilities to use the Irish language (or lack thereof).

To what degree is the new Taoiseach, Leo Varadkar, proficient in various aspects of the language (i.e. reading, writing, speaking)? What has been  the reaction to his Irish language skills from pro-Irish language bodies and politicians?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He has completed the [Gaelchultúr Level 4 course](http://gaelchultur.com/en/certificate_level4.aspx) for public and civil servants
He says and I Quote from [this](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/politics/c%C3%BApla-focal-should-the-next-taoiseach-be-able-to-speak-irish-1.3089211?mode=amp) article:

> It’s getting better but I’m far from fluent.

So no he isn't fluent. It is worth noting his rival wasn't fluent either

> Mr Varadkar’s rival Minister for Housing Simon Coveney’s level of proficiency is described as “basic”, although he has taken some lessons

Comment: It's worth noting that not very many Irish are fluent in the Irish language; it's compulsory on schools, but many simply forget much of it after they leave school. Irish is frequently spoken only in certain geographical areas, which prop up the nationwide number of speakers to about 10% at the most.

Comment: Great answer! Are you aware of any reactions to his Irish skills from various  pro-Irish language bodies/lobby groups?

Comment: @suitvertices Not really, but I suspect that's because his level of proficiency is just about that of every Taoiseach

Comment: s/every/every recent/ @<>SleepingGod . @martin-tournoij There are many opt-outs to avoid learning it in school. Though, you have to fulfill criteria to be exempt.